# Android Preference remove line above list detail?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

I use AppCompatPreferenceActivity, and test on Sony Xperia Tablet S (4.1.1 - API 16)
How can I remove the black line above the list?

[image]

Comment: I think this is created by system, we can not hide it,but it works well in various os version like android 6.0 or others.

Comment: Will you add your code?

Comment: Please provide your code here, so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

you can hide the line by below code

```
  View rView = getView();
    ListView l = (ListView) rView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    l.setDivider(null);
```

Comment: Your solution only affects the divider of listview, the line above listview still keeps color.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
listView.setHeaderDividersEnabled(false);
```

For more explanation see this link

```
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android:headerDividersEnabled
```

Comment: Unfornately, the line is not header divider.

Comment: Oh i thought it was header..then what is that line?